# XSS - Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, security, xss, content-security-policy

Can XSS be prevented 100% by setting the content security policy as default-src 'self'? Is there any way XSS can happen in that case? One possibility I can think of is injecting user input into one of your scripts dynamically at the server-side, do you agree? Are there any other vulnerabilities you can think of?

Answer (score 2):

No, CSP is not a magic bullet. It should be one line of defense, not the entire defense. If properly configured it can help

- preventing usable XSS where the payload, whether persistent or reflected must be small and therefore would usually just create a script element and inject external code
- avoiding data extraction and misuse as platform to attack other sites. Depending on how your application works, access to your backend service may suffice to extract data, for instance, if your users can write blog posts an attacker could create a new post with the data it needs to extract, wait for a signal that the data has been grabbed (via a comment for instance) and delete the post again, all without communicating with external servers.

Comment: Do you have an example of how malicious JS can end up being run by the browser despite the default-src 'self' CSP? (Of course considering the browser supports CSP)

Comment: Usually the injection part is not using external resources. A persistent XSS is just your database dumping out someone elses JS, but you are still the origin. Reflected XSS is usually injected via request parameters or request body contents, again your server is the one serving the Javascript. If you can inject `<script src="https://evil-server.example.org/evil.js"></script>`, you can also inject `<script>alert('XSS!')</script>`, where the alert can be replaced by the contents of `evil.js`

Comment: Neither of the examples described above would fire given `default-src 'self'`.

Comment: Except the alert would. My point being that if you can reflect a script tag with src, you can probably do the same for the entire malicious script.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, yes a modern browser with `default-src 'self'` can still execute user-controlled javascript: `JSONP`.

> Of particular note is our lack of `self` in our source list. While
>   sourcing JavaScript from `self` seems relatively safe (and extremely
>   common), it should be avoided when possible.
>
> There are edge cases that any developer must concern themselves with
>   when allowing self as a source for scripts. There may be a forgotten
>   `JSONP` endpoint that doesn’t sanitize the callback function name.

From http://githubengineering.com/githubs-csp-journey/

Answer (score 1):

CSP should not be used as the only way to prevent XSS attack. This mechanism works only client side (If you save malicious data into your DB, then you can probably start infecting other systems that you integrating with) and it's not implemented by all browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=csp).

To prevent XSS you should always validate input data and encode output data. You can also print warning message in JavaScript console to prevent somehow Self-XSS attacks (ex. open facebook page and turn on Chrome Developers Tools - look at the message in console).

Remember that the user input on the website is not the only source of XSS. Malicious data can also come from:

1. Importing data from files
2. Importing data from third party systems
3. Migration data from old system.
4. Cookies and http headers.

If you have appropriate validation and encoding of data (server side), then you can additionally apply browser mechanism such as: CSP, X-XSS-Protection or X-Content-Type-Options to increase your confidence about your system safety.

Comment: What kind of heuristic are we talking about? There isn't much room for interpretation if you setup your rules properly. It's pretty much SPF for the web.

Comment: Thank for your attention. I corrected my answer. X-XSS-Protection is based on the heuristic not CSP.

Comment: Do you have an example of how malicious JS can end up being run by the browser despite the default-src 'self' CSP? (Of course considering the browser supports CSP)

Comment: I don't have example of JS code, but XSS is not only about JS. For example attacker can inject hidden fields into your form and override values provided by user.